# SQL Server 2008 R2: Dynamic Pivot Query - COALESCE Unclosed quotation error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, dynamic, pivot

I have tried a few options but I seem to be stuck on the column name string.  When creating the the column name the ' seems to be truncated. Can you help me resolve.

```
declare @columns as varchar(7)
declare @AMG_Pivot as varchar(max)

select @columns=
coalesce(@columns + ',','') + quotename ([MM-YYYY])
from
(
 SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(2), month ([MEMBER_MONTH_DAY])) + '-' + convert(varchar(4), year([MEMBER_MONTH_DAY])) as [MM-YYYY] 
    FROM Sindle.DBO.AMG_MM) A


    SET @AMG_Pivot = 
    '


SELECT PHS_ORG, PCP_Name, [PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME], [AGE_TYPE], '+@columns+', [PATIENT_ID] 
    FROM Sindle.DBO.AMG_MM



PIVOT (COUNT([PATIENT_ID]) FOR [MM-YYYY] IN ( '  +@columns+ ')) PT
Order By phs_org,PCP_NAME,PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME,AGE_TYPE'

EXEC (@AMG_Pivot)
```

and here is the error message I get

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '6-2016)) PT
>   Order By phs_org,PCP_NAME,PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME,AGE_TYPE'.

= = = = = = = = = = =

I am trying to convert my pivot into one with dynamic headings but I keep getting two errors.

**My original query - this behaves as expected**

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT PHS_ORG, PCP_Name, [PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME], [AGE_TYPE], convert(varchar(2), month ([MEMBER_MONTH_DAY])) + '-' + convert(varchar(4), year([MEMBER_MONTH_DAY])) as [MM-YYYY], [PATIENT_ID] 
    FROM Sindle.DBO.AMG_MM) T
PIVOT (COUNT([PATIENT_ID]) FOR [MM-YYYY] IN ([6-2015],[7-2015],[8-2015],[9-2015],[10-2015],[11-2015],[12-2015],[1-2016],[2-2016],[3-2016],[4-2016],[5-2016],[6-2016])) PT
Order By phs_org,PCP_NAME,PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME,AGE_TYPE
```

**Unfortunately when I try to set the column names I get two errors**

```
declare @columns as varchar(7)
declare @AMG_Pivot as varchar(max)

select @columns=
coalesce(@columns+',','') + quotename ('MM-YYY')
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(2), month ([MEMBER_MONTH_DAY])) + '-' + convert(varchar(4), year([MEMBER_MONTH_DAY])) as [MM-YYYY] 
    FROM Sindle.DBO.AMG_MM) A


    SET @AMG_Pivot = '

    SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT PHS_ORG, PCP_Name, [PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME], [AGE_TYPE], '+@columns+', [PATIENT_ID] 
    FROM A) t



PIVOT (COUNT([PATIENT_ID]) FOR [MM-YYYY] IN ('+@columns+')) PT
Order By phs_org,PCP_NAME,PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME,AGE_TYPE'

EXEC (@AMG_Pivot)
```

**Here are the errors I am getting.** Any help would be appreciated.

`Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'MM-YYY)) PT
Order By phs_org,PCP_NAME,PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME,AGE_TYPE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'MM-YYY)) PT
Order By phs_org,PCP_NAME,PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME,AGE_TYPE'.`

**If I change the EXEC statement to a SELECT statement I simply get a string containing the text:**

> SELECT *
>   FROM 
>   (
>     SELECT PHS_ORG, PCP_Name, [PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME], [AGE_TYPE], '+@columns+', [PATIENT_ID] 
>           FROM A) t
>
> PIVOT (COUNT([PATIENT_ID]) FOR [MM-YYYY] IN ('+@columns+')) PT
>   Order By phs_org,PCP_NAME,PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME,AGE_TYPE

[image of select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNNOS.png)

Comment: Can you post what @AMG_Pivot contains?  You might already know but using select instead of exec will give you that.  If we could see that it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @JoeC  I am confused about question. 

 AMG_Pivot = '

    SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT PHS_ORG, PCP_Name, [PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME], [AGE_TYPE], '+@columns+', [PATIENT_ID] 
    FROM A) t



PIVOT (COUNT([PATIENT_ID]) FOR [MM-YYYY] IN ('+@columns+')) PT
Order By phs_org,PCP_NAME,PLAN_TYPE_C_NAME,AGE_TYPE'

Comment: If you change the line Exec (AMG_Pivot) to Select @AMG_Pivot then the contents of the variable will go to your results window.  That will show us the exact query being executed and will make it easier to determine the error.  I suspect it may be in the columns variable but showing the Sql should clear it up for certain.

Comment: @JoeC a string containing the text is reutrned

Comment: Ok cool please edit your question with that text.

Comment: is the value of @columns what you expect?  I wouldn't think varchar(7) would be big enough for more than one yyyy-mm,

Comment: @Beth yes the value returned is what I expect